# Although the element is displayed on the webpage, the command .isDisplayed() returns false

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Although the icons, heading and subheading are present on the webpage, the `.isDisplayed()` method always returns false.

Can someone tell me why does it return false for these elements on the webpage?

Methods:

```
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class TeamURLPageFactory {

        static WebDriver driver;
        public static WebElement element = null;
        private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(TeamURLPageFactory.class.getName());
        static String TeamName2 = "BlockedExtContact";
        static String TeamDomain2 = "farzanshaikh.com";

        public static WebElement errorIcon(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='error-icon']"));
        log.info("Error Icon Element Found");
        return element;
    }

    public static void errorIconDisplayed(WebDriver driver){
        element = errorIcon(driver);
        if(element.isDisplayed()){
            log.info("Error Icon is Displayed");
        }else{
            log.error("Error Icon is Not Displayed");
        }
    }

    public static WebElement errorHeading(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='block-error']/h2"));
        log.info("Error Heading Element Found");
        return element;
    }

    public static void errorHeadingDisplayed(WebDriver driver){
        element = errorHeading(driver);
        if(element.isDisplayed()){
            log.info("Header on the Error Block is displayed");
        }else{
            log.error("Header on the Error Block is not displayed");
        }
    }


    public static WebElement errorSubHeading(WebDriver driver){
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='block-error']/p"));
        log.info("Error SubHeading Element Found");
        return element;
    }

    public static void errorSubHeadingDisplayed(WebDriver driver){
        element = errorSubHeading(driver);
        if(element.isDisplayed()){
            log.info("SubHeader on the Error Block is displayed");
        }else{
            log.error("SubHeader on the Error Block is not displayed");
        }
    }

}
```

Main Code:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;;

public class FlockTeamURLDomain {
    static WebDriver driver;
    static String TeamUrl3 = "https://blockedextcontact.flock.com/";
    String TeamName = "<script>farzan</script>";
    String TeamDomain = "farzanshaikh.com";
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(FlockTeamURLDomain.class.getName());

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(TeamUrl3);
    }
    @Test
    public void blockError() throws Exception{
        driver.get(TeamUrl3);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        TeamURLPageFactory.errorIconDisplayed(driver);
        TeamURLPageFactory.errorHeadingDisplayed(driver);
        TeamURLPageFactory.errorSubHeadingDisplayed(driver);

    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Comment: For questions like this, while code is helpful, at least a snippet of the HTML would probably help more.  Please add it to your original question.

Comment: They are present on the DOM but not viewable on the screen that's why .isDisplayed() returns false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Selenium code for the `isDisplayed()` method, for here - [link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/dom.js)

```
 /**
 * Determines whether an element is what a user would call "shown". This means
 * that the element is shown in the viewport of the browser, and only has height and width greater than 0px, and that its visibility is not "hidden".
 * and its display property is not "none".
 * Options and Optgroup elements are treated as special cases: they are
 * considered shown iff they have a enclosing select element that is shown.
 *
 * Elements in Shadow DOMs with younger shadow roots are not visible, and
 * elements distributed into shadow DOMs check the visibility of the
 * ancestors in the Composed DOM, rather than their ancestors in the logical
* DOM.
*
```

Please check if the DOM doesn't has the element hidden, which might be the reason for this.

Also, you can check `element.size()!=0` if the element is displayed on the webpage.

Comment: Element.size()!=0 should return true even if an element is present on DOM, but not visible on webpage.

Comment: @bad_deadpool Great analysis

Comment: @bad_deadpool Thanx guys